# Why won't my dual-boot system start after being shut down for a few days?

Tags: boot-failure

I  have windows7 & ubuntu,  After several days in shudown position,My system is not booting now. I an not even getting grub for OS selection. 
I have important data in hard disc
How to restore & get important data?

Comment: Try [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: most probably seems Hardware problem.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is follow the documentation here. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Basically there a few methods, but the easiest is just making a CD with the ISO on it listed on the page. https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/

It is a simple process and should get you back up and running.